# Take a text line in an image file to create a new image file MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to take each line of text from an image file and create a new separate image for each of the lines. i already have a way to count how many lines are in the image file.

if anybody has any suggestions it would be a huge help because i'm not too good with images.  im not allowed to use the image processing toolbox.

This is the code:

```
function out = countLines( imgFile )
% count the number of lines in the image file
im = imread(imgFile);
im = 255 - im;
imbw = uint8(0.33*im(:,:,1) + 0.34*im(:,:,2) + 0.33*im(:,:,3)) > 127;
imwrite(imbw, 'temp.jpg');
rvec = sum(imbw');
rvec1 = [0 rvec 0];
svec = [rvec 0 0];
out = sum(rvec1 == 0 & svec ~= 0);
```

Comment: Could you show an example of an image you have to deal with?

Comment: and maybe a bit of code explaining what you did?

Comment: i cant get my code to format correctly in this textbox

Comment: my image file is just a jpeg with a white background with black text

Comment: One option is to do what you've done so far with `rvec` and search for its local minima. The resulting row numbers would be the dividing lines for the lines of text. As an aside, the `rgb2gray()` function can convert RGB images to greyscale.

Comment: so if i use rgb2gray(rvec) wont it output the entire image instead of just the one line that i want? or is this a different way?

Comment: I showed you the code for counting the number of lines of text in an image using Matlab. I want to now count the letters. My algorithm is to save each line as a new image, rotate the image by 90, so each line is now a letter and sum all of them at the end. I know how to do everything except for isolate an entire line. That is all I need help with: isolating a line of text.

Comment: Did you understand my suggestion about finding the local *maxima* (sorry for error) of `rvec`? These would be the "whitest" rows, so you could use these rows to splice your image into lines. My other point was that you could do `imgray = rgb2gray(im)` to get a greyscale version of the image, rather than use the technique in line 5 of your code.

Comment: no i was not sure of what the maxima was supposed to do. im not familiar with that term... im really new to programming so some of this is difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this method on a test image I found on the internet and it seemed to work alright provided the text is straight. Basically you look for entries in your `rvec` vector whose neighbouring entries are both smaller than them. That is to say you look for the local maximum entries (first image). After that you group the clusters of lines together to decide where to split the image (second image).

[image]
[image]

```
clear; clc; 

im = imread('text.png');        % load the image
[Nrows,Ncols,~] = size(im);     % get the size
imgray = rgb2gray(im);          % convert to grayscale

vec = mean(imgray,2);           % average intensities of each row
localMax=[];                    % list of local maximum entries

for i = 2:Nrows-1               % accept local max rows that do not have text
    hasText = sum( imgray(i,:)<100 )>0;
    if vec(i)>vec(i-1) && vec(i)>vec(i+1) && ~hasText
        localMax = [localMax;i];
    end
end


numMax = length(localMax);      
                                % get distances between local max rows
distances = localMax(2:end) - localMax(1:end-1);
thresh = mean(distances);       % the average distance will be our threshold

splitRows = [];                 % rows where we will split the image
cluster = localMax(1);          % start a cluster with the first local max row 

for i = 1:numMax-1;             
    if distances(i) < thresh    % if rows are close together, keep them in a cluster
        cluster = [cluster;localMax(i+1)];
    else                        % average the cluster to get the row where we split the image
        newSplit = round(mean(cluster)); 
        splitRows = [ splitRows ; newSplit ];
        cluster = localMax(i+1);
    end
end
newSplit = round(mean(cluster)); % add the last cluster as well
splitRows = [ splitRows ; newSplit ];
```

Comment: Thank you man this works for what i was trying to do. i really appreciate the help. sorry for the delayed response